# Fetching Discord Profile Picture from ID discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am wondering how I can fetch the profile picture of a discord user without my bot being in a server with them. https://discord.id can do this and I'm wondering how I could in discord.py. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use something like this:

```py
User = await client.fetch_user(DISCORD_ID_HERE)
print(User.avatar) # this will print the link to the users profile picture!
```

for even more info I'd suggestion reading [discord.py's documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute (actually it is a `@property`) [`.avatar_url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.avatar_url) of class `discord.Member`, it will give you the link to the avatar.

Notice that sending the bare url in Discord will create an embed with the image, so probably you don't even need to download the image.

---

Also class `discord.User` has an [`avatar_url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User.avatar_url) attribute, so you can fetch the user using the [`fetch_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user) method

```
await Bot.fetch_user(id)
```

and then get the `avatar` reading the property `avatar_url`.

Comment: How would you get the member without being in the same server? This is not clear in the answer.

Comment: In this case discord.id must have a REST API, but this isn't a pure Discord.py solution.

Comment: It's definitely possible with discord.py, see [`fetch_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user)